# Doubleval function of PHP to Python

Tags: php, python-2.7, function

Is there a equivalent function `doubleval()` of PHP in Python? or any function that can convert this example:

```
var = '10.3211E2'
```

into this

```
var = 1032.11
```

Comment: I don't use PHP, but what is wrong with doing `var *= 100` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I shift the decimal place in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8362792/how-do-i-shift-the-decimal-place-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

`doubleval()` in PHP is used to get a float value of a variable. You can use `float()` in Python to get the value extracted.

```
string="41.68127E3"
print(float(string))
```

---

```
41681.27
```