# ValueError: could not convert string to float: '7.112,9' (Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, replace

[I have this data from .csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3gwuZ.png)

```
bitcoin[['Dernier']] = bitcoin[['Dernier']].astype(float)

if copy or is_object_dtype(arr) or is_object_dtype(dtype):

# Explicit copy, or required since NumPy can't view from / to object.
return arr.astype(dtype, copy=True)
return arr.view(dtype)
```

**Output:**

> ValueError: could not convert string to float: '7.112,9'

Comment: remove comma & try ```bitcoin[['Dernier']].fillna('').str.replace(',',"").astype(float)```

Comment: AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'str'

Comment: try this, bitcoin['Dernier'].fillna('').str.replace(',',"").astype(float)

Comment: dataframe[arry] will return dataframe, above code will return series.

Comment: bitcoin['Dernier']=bitcoin['Dernier'].fillna('').str.replace(',',"").astype(float)

Comment: Perfect it's works !!!! tnx

Comment: I want to see : 7112.9 and not   7.1129     any idea ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8362792/how-do-i-shift-the-decimal-place-in-python